# Reverse Wild Card Vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, wildcard, vlookup

I'm trying to perform to me what seems like a reverse wildcard lookup, but if anyone has suggestions on a better formula I'm totally open to that.

I have a column that has multiple words in the cell ex:(the house was brown), and then I have a table that has a column of colors and a column of values ex:(A2=brown, B2=1738) and what I would like to do is run a vlookup off (the house is brown) and return with the 1738 value.

In my mind the formula looks like this

```
=vlookup("the house was brown",sheet2!"*"&A:B&"*",2,false)
```

Where the wild cards are attached to the lookup values, but that doesn't seem to work and I've played around with the placement of the wildcards and have turned up with nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: google sheets please

Comment: what if there are two matches in the list?

Comment: @ScottCraner for this project it wouldn't really matter if there were multiple matches on the list as long as it returned one of them. Ideally, it would be an exact match but doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the question, you have data like:

Data in A1:A4
The mouse is brown
The house is brown
The car is red
The robin is red

supplemented by a lookup table of the form

Named Range "LookupTable"
Col1 ; Col2
brown; 5
red; 6
blue; 7
etc.

Then the formula,

```
=trim(join(" ",arrayformula(iferror(vlookup((iferror(regexextract(lower(A1),"\b"&LookupTableCol1&"\b"),"")),LookupTable,2,FALSE),""))))
```

in B1:B4, where A1 is the top-right of the LookupTable, gives the output

Output:
5
5 6
6
6

That is, every instance of the word of the lookup table is identified by the associated number, and those numbers are listed (space separated) one at a time in a single cell.

Note that the lookup table must be in lower case to get positive matches.

Is that what you were after?

For the sake of editing, testing, or refining the answer here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b_tJ3VXxs4B9UUKXdyN-AbNP9h7mTLB_iLnI6YGKYXs/edit#gid=0) to a spreadsheet showing this in action which I'll remove once the answer's accepted.

**Clarification of how this works**
This works by

(1) Using by using a regular expression with a string literal to identify the presence of one of the lookup words in LookupTableCol1. The "\b" part added to each end ensures that it is matched as a whole word, and the lower() function is used to ensure our results are not case-sensitive.
(2) This is then inputted into vlookup() to search for that word in the lookup table and return the associated value.
(3) An "iferror()" is used to remove any "N/A" errors if no matches are found in the regexextract() or the vlookup().
(4) Arrayformula() is used to repeat these actions down LookupTableCol1 and return an array
(5) Join() is used to concatenate the whole array into a single cell for readability.
(6) Trim() is used to remove any leading or trailing spaces resulting from blank cells in the array returned from arrayformula as a result of using join() with an array containing blank cells.

Comment: Hey @Paul thanks for the answer! I'm still having a little bit of trouble getting it to work. Perhaps if I share the data I'm working with might help. Here is a link to a copy of what I'm working on [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yiezA3otwg2XQf6_cvCcdRfupMwpRbdMtI0YLTzClOs/edit?usp=sharing) There's a data table, and the highlighted cell on the lookup table contains the formula. Thanks again!

Comment: @RickyAdams Like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1REog_SEAJGdWwlkGLYKyYEOOAFmtlNCKevxxdrcGBAI/edit#gid=969580369)? I'll add another edit to explain.

Comment: @RickyAdams I've updated the answer now I know the specific situation a bit better.  Basically, I've added something to ensure you're only matching whole words (and not if that word is in another word), and also to remove any case-sensitivity. Please remember to accept the answer if this solves your problem to indicate to others that this is a valid solution, if someone comes across this in future.

Comment: This works perfectly! I just have one last question. Is there a way to add the array formula on to the outside? I'm trying to automate it so that every time I add a new row the formula automatically fills into that row for that column. Here is what I'm trying to do, but when I go to edit the (A1) to (A:A) it comes up with an error: =ARRAYFORMULA(if($A$2:$A="",,(trim(join(" ",arrayformula(iferror(vlookup((iferror(regexextract(lower(A:A),"\b"&LookupTableCol1&"\b"),"")),LookupTable,2,FALSE),"")))))))

Comment: @RickyAdams The way I constructed this will mean you have to copy the formula down all of the cells in the column. It should return blanks if there is no input so you could just add a lot of rows and copy it down. If that doesn't work then, at least to me, it's time to use Google App Script.

Comment: Ah yeah that won't work for this because the sheet is liked to Automate.io and has a new row trigger to push to slack, so ive been automating new row formulas with the =ARRAYFORMULA(if($A$2:$A="",, part in front of all of my formulas. Any suggestions on a google app script for this? Thanks again! Marking this as solved since you totally figured out the original questions!